# Test if a function is asynchronous or not?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I want to test whether a function in node.js is asynchronous or not?

The author of the module says that its asynchronous but I want to be sure. I was hoping there was some way to find out if its truly asynchronous or not. So how can I check that whether its asynchronous or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "asynchronous"?  If it returns data via a callback instead of return value, it is asynchronous as far as you should care.

Comment: That is incorrect, callbacks will still execute synchronously unless timers or `process.nextTick()` are involved.

Comment: Callbacks doesn't mean they are async. Yeah every asynchronous function have callback but that doesn't mean every function having callback is asynchronous.

Comment: The only way to really know what the module is doing is to read its source code.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple way to test if the code is async: modify a variable in the callback and check if it has changed after the function call:

```
var async_check = 0;

maybe_async(function(){
    async_check = 1;
});

if(async_check){
    console.log("maybe_async was synchronous");
}
else {
    console.log("maybe_async was asynchronous");
}
```